# VueJS – Programmatically write component from looped object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have 3 tabs in a single file component, within the tab content for each of these tabs I would like to include a component for each tab.  I'm looping through a array of (tab) objects.

**Template:**

```
<v-tabs v-model="currentTab">
   <v-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="'tab-' + tab.name">
      <v-icon class="mr-2" small v-html="tab.icon"></v-icon>
        {{ tab.title }}
      </v-tab>
   </v-tab>
</v-tabs>

<v-tabs-items v-model="currentTab">
   <v-tab-item v-for="tab in tabs" :key="'tab-content-' + tab.name">

      <!-- **COMPONENT HERE** -->

   </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

And the array of tab objects, the component specified in the object is imported at the beginning of the script.

**Data (tabs array):**

```
  currentTab: null,
  tabs: [
    {
      name: 'details',
      icon: 'business',
      title: 'Company Details',
      component: CompanyDetails
    },
    {
      name: 'statistics',
      icon: 'bar_chart',
      title: 'Statistics',
      component: CompanyStats
    },
    {
      name: 'contacts',
      icon: 'contacts',
      title: 'Contacts',
      component: CompanyContacts
    }
  ]
```

**Imports:**

```
import CompanyDetails from './CompanyModal/CompanyDetails'
import CompanyStats from './CompanyModal/CompanyDetails'
import CompanyContacts from './CompanyModal/CompanyContacts'
```

Is this even possible?  It doesn't seem to be in the docs and I can't find any discussions about it anywhere.

Comment: uses [Vue dynamic components :is](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is)

Comment: Nailed it, dunno how I missed that, thanks!